# iMacros: How can I select multiple items in a very basic combo box?

Tags: imacros

A website I work with has a very basic option box set up and I'm trying to create an iMacro that will select multiple values from it on the screen so that I can manually submit the send button. The code looks like this,

```
<form method="POST">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
    Dinners: <br/>
<select style="width:auto;" name="dinner:menu" size="10" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="steak" >steak</option> <option value="fish" >fish</option> <option value="rolls" >rolls</option> <option value="chicken" >chicken</option> <option value="fries" >fries</option> <option value="pizza" >pizza</option> <option value="hamburger" >hamburger</option> <option value="cheese" >cheese</option> 
</select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Was this just created too simple for iMacro to be able to identify the options? I want to be able to select multiple ones on screen automatically.

I was basing my attempts off of,
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=NAME:select1 CONTENT=$Apple

Comment: "*Was this just created too simple for iMacro[s] to be able to identify the options?*", LOL...! => It's completely documented in the Wiki, => read the Documentation... :idea:

Comment: Look, I'm trying. I spent a whole lot of time this morning going through the documentation and it's just not clicking for me. I'm very new to this. Samples / Examples it says to try point to elements that don't seem to be defined in just a regular table with option params.

Comment: Well, [Link](https://wiki.imacros.net/TAG#Special_TAG_Commands_for_Drop_Down_Menus) to the Wiki if you didn't find it, and a Quote: "*Multiple selection can be achieved by listing indices separated by a colon (`:`).*" And + 2 Examples: `CONTENT=$Apple:$*berry*:$Peach` and `CONTENT=#1:#3:#8`.

Comment: Thank you chivracq. I just got it working. I had to really dumb down my list, TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=NAME:dinner:menu CONTENT=$fish  . So it shouldn't be hard to do multiples with your example. Thank you for taking some time to point me in the right direction, it's appreciated.